# To call any R package from python

Tags: python, apriori

Please let me know the procedure, what settings needed to call R packages from Python.

I use Spyder (python 2.7)

I am trying to call apriori package from Python.it fails in arules.

Any help would be appreciated.

I already tried the following

```
import rpy2

from rpy2 import *
import rpy2.interactive as r

arules = r.packages.importr("arules")
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import ListVector

od = OrderedDict()
od["supp"] = 0.0005
od["conf"] = 0.7
od["target"] = 'rules'

result = ListVector(od)

dataset = 'c:/Apriori/testcase.txt'

my_rules = arules.apriori(dataset, parameter=result)

print('my_rules',my_rules)
```